# JQ Filter for parent IDs and child IDs with date evaluation

Tags: curl, jq

I am on a tight deadline and working on a work around for a product that is not exposing a SQL view but does expose some elements via API. Looking to do this processing in the PIPE after the curl query.

Reproduction:

```
curl -x GET -u {credentials} {endpoint fqdn} | jq

    {
  "total_count": 34,
  "Passwords": [
    {
      "username": "testusername",
      "category": null,
      "device_ids": [],
      "view_users": "",
      "view_groups": "",
      "last_pw_change": "2021-04-13T13:30:03Z",
      "notes": "",
      "storage": "Normal",
      "use_only_users": "",
      "label": "EXPIRED",
      "view_edit_groups": "",
      "first_added": "2021-04-13T13:30:03.790Z",
      "use_only_groups": "",
      "storage_id": 1,
      "view_edit_users": "admin",
      "password": "",
      "id": 36,
      "custom_fields": [
        {
          "notes": null,
          "key": "expiry-event",
          "value": "2021-4-13"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

Above is an example of what is returned via curl. I'd like to be able to grab the USERNAME, STORAGE_ID, and then the CUSTOM_FIELDS > KEY and CUSTOM_FIELDS > VALUE

WHEN the Key = expiry-event
and the VALUE for that key is prior to today's date.

Is this possible with JQ filtering? I am not sure that the date option is a function in JQ. But any help getting as close as possible would be appreciated.

I've tried filtering into separate arrays but I get a FAILED TO BUILD BODY error. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, the result would show 

username: testusername
storage_id: 1
key: expiry-date
value: 2021-4-13 

and only show the expiry key (it's possible to have more than 1 custom-field) and the date be prior to today()

Comment: The title mentions "jquery". Did you mean "jq"?  Also, in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines, please give a complete example, showing the output you expect corresponding to the sample input, which incidentally has an extra comma that makes it technically invalid as JSON.

Comment: Hi @peak apologies on the title. Ive correct that. The result is displayed. Its simply an API request with a | to jq. Ive added that to the example as well.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample input (without the extra comma that makes it technically invalid as JSON), the following produces the output shown below:

```
def prior($yymmdd): sub("-(?<d>\\d)-"; "-0\(.d)-") <= ($yymmdd);

(now|strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d")) as $now
| .Passwords[]
| {username,
   storage,
   custom_fields : .custom_fields | map(select(.key == "expiry-event" and (.value|prior($now)))) }
```

You can easily remove any unwanted fields, e.g. using `del/1`, or by specifying the keys you do want.

#### Output

```
{
  "username": "testusername",
  "storage": "Normal",
  "custom_fields": [
    {
      "notes": null,
      "key": "expiry-event",
      "value": "2021-4-13"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @peak I was able to get this to process however it is returning all results. It's limiting to the correct fields but is returning every result in the system. I made 3 records with the custom field filled out. 2 are in the past and 1 is in the future. I would expect to only retrieve the 2 dated in the past. Instead I am getting all records, even ones that do not have the field filled out and the record in the future as well. I am submitting the request like this:

Comment: curl -k -X GET -u 'HIDDEN' 'https://12.34.56.789/api/1.0/passwords/' | jq 'def prior($yymmdd): sub("-(?<d>\\d)-"; "-0\(.d)-") <= ($yymmdd); (now|strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d")) as $now | .Passwords[] | {username, storage, custom_fields : .custom_fields | map(select(.key == "expiry-event" and (.value|prior($now))))}'

Comment: Maybe you could update the Q and give a minimal but incise example in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines. (It would be OK to give more than one example altogether.)

Comment: Again... this is the example. Its a query to an API endpoint and post manipulation with JQ. Ive shared the API request and the resultant data set. Ive shared my desired output. There's no more data to provide and it is meeting examples in the doc for minimal reproducible examples. You wont be able to specifically reproduce unless you own the same product, which I guarantee you would not unless you own and Enterprise company.